# Default string resource not used when not included in locale

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

My default strings resource file at app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml has the following value defined:

```
<string name="locale">en_GB</string>
```

I have an override strings resource file for en_US at app/src/main/values-en-rUS/strings.xml:

```
<string name="locale">en_US</string>
```

Finally, I have another strings resource file for en_CA at app/src/main/values-en-rCA/strings.xml that doesn't override that particular value.

Here's how I'm using this value:

```
var locale = context.getString(R.string.locale)
```

I specified my preferred language as English (Canada) in the system settings, so I would expect it to use the value from the default strings resource file and assign "en_GB" to `locale`. However, it's using the value from the override and assigning "en_US" to `locale`. The only way I can get it to assign the correct value is to duplicate the default by adding this line to the file at app/src/main/values-en-rCA/strings.xml:

```
<string name="locale">en_GB</string>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?